# Why did I get IndexOutOfBoundException in this program?

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans

This program uses the ArrayList class, and I get an Exception while running, what is the problem? I couldn't find any logical problem!

```
public static ArrayList<Double> differenceArray(ArrayList<Double> a, double avg) {

    ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>(a.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        temp.set(i, avg - a.get(i));

    }
    return temp;
}

public static void showScoresDiff(ArrayList<Double> a) {

    fillArray(a);
    double avg = computeAvg(a);
    double diff;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

        diff = avg - a.get(i);

        System.out.println("the diffrence between the avarege " + avg + " and the element " + a.get(i) + " is " + Math.abs(diff));
    }

    System.out.println("\n");

    ArrayList<Double> newArray = differenceArray(a, avg);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("The " + (i + 1) + "th " + "element of the difference array is: " + newArray.get(i));
    }
}
```

{
and here is the output:
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EEYU.png)

> Blockquote

Comment: Add something to an empty list with [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-), not [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there in the following lines:

```
 ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>(a.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        temp.set(i, avg - a.get(i));
```

The statement, `ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>(a.size())` does not initialize `temp` with as many elements as `a.size()` i.e. the size of `temp` is still `0` after this statement is executed.

Given below is the [description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) of `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`:

> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Since the size of `temp` is `0`, the statement,  `temp.set(i, avg - a.get(i))` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If you want `temp` to be initialized with the elements of `a`, you can do it as follows:

```
ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>(a);
```

Now, you can set the elements up to the index, `a.size() - 1`.

--OR--

If you simply want to add something to `temp`, you can use [`ArrayList#add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) e.g. `temp.add(5.5)`.